# seeking for help on webpack 2 migration fail

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

First of all sorry to paste this ugly build fail log... but i am frustrated. i can see the failure coming from `ld-redux` with `uuid`, then somehow it went into `crypto-browserify/test`, anyone have similar issue can give a helpful hand please?

Thanks very much

```
ERROR in ./~/crypto-browserify/test/create-hash.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tape' in '/Users/billluo/Git/assurewebsite/node_modules/crypto-browserify/test'
 @ ./~/crypto-browserify/test/create-hash.js 1:11-26
 @ ./~/crypto-browserify/index.js
 @ ./~/node-uuid/uuid.js
 @ ./~/ld-redux/lib/init.js
 @ ./~/ld-redux/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/universal/domain/health/products/combinedProducts.js
 @ ./src/universal/routes.js
 @ ./src/client/index.js
 @ multi babel-polyfill webpack-dev-server/client?http://192.168.2.51:8001 webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./src/client/index

ERROR in ./~/crypto-browserify/test/create-hmac.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tape' in '/Users/billluo/Git/assurewebsite/node_modules/crypto-browserify/test'
 @ ./~/crypto-browserify/test/create-hmac.js 1:11-26
 @ ./~/crypto-browserify/index.js
 @ ./~/node-uuid/uuid.js
 @ ./~/ld-redux/lib/init.js
 @ ./~/ld-redux/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/universal/domain/health/products/combinedProducts.js
 @ ./src/universal/routes.js
 @ ./src/client/index.js
 @ multi babel-polyfill webpack-dev-server/client?http://192.168.2.51:8001 webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./src/client/index

ERROR in ./~/crypto-browserify/test/pbkdf2.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tape' in '/Users/billluo/Git/assurewebsite/node_modules/crypto-browserify/test'
 @ ./~/crypto-browserify/test/pbkdf2.js 1:11-26
 @ ./~/crypto-browserify/index.js
 @ ./~/node-uuid/uuid.js
 @ ./~/ld-redux/lib/init.js
 @ ./~/ld-redux/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/universal/domain/health/products/combinedProducts.js
 @ ./src/universal/routes.js
 @ ./src/client/index.js
 @ multi babel-polyfill webpack-dev-server/client?http://192.168.2.51:8001 webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./src/client/index

ERROR in ./~/crypto-browserify/test/public-encrypt.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'tape' in '/Users/billluo/Git/assurewebsite/node_modules/crypto-browserify/test'
 @ ./~/crypto-browserify/test/public-encrypt.js 1:11-26
 @ ./~/crypto-browserify/index.js
 @ ./~/node-uuid/uuid.js
 @ ./~/ld-redux/lib/init.js
 @ ./~/ld-redux/lib/index.js
 @ ./src/universal/domain/health/products/combinedProducts.js
 @ ./src/universal/routes.js
 @ ./src/client/index.js
 @ multi babel-polyfill webpack-dev-server/client?http://192.168.2.51:8001 webpack/hot/only-dev-server ./src/client/index
```

here is my build script

```
import autoprefixer from 'autoprefixer';
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import AssetsPlugin from 'assets-webpack-plugin';
import config from 'config';
import ipAddress from '../../src/universal/utils/ipAddress';

const root = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..');
const appSourceFolder = path.resolve(root, 'src');
const devServerUrl = `http://${ipAddress}:${config.port + 1}`;

// We use SVGO to optimise the imported SVG files
const svgoConfig = JSON.stringify({
  plugins: [
    {removeTitle: true},
    {removeAttrs: {attrs: 'fill'}},
  ],
});

export default {
  devtool: 'source-map', // Note: changed from cheap-module-inline-source-map to eval-source-map due to issues setting breakpoints reliably
  debug: true, // switch loaders to debug mode
  entry: [
    'babel-polyfill',
    `webpack-dev-server/client?${devServerUrl}`,
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/client/index',
  ],
  target: 'web',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(root, 'dist'),
    pathinfo: true, // Add /* filename */ comments to generated require()s in the output.
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: `${devServerUrl}/dist/`,
  },
  externals: [{
    config: 'config',
  }],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.json'],
    modulesDirectories: [
      'assets',
      'src',
      'test',
      'node_modules',
    ],
  },
  module: {
    // run eslint before compiling
    preLoaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        include: appSourceFolder,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: appSourceFolder,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['react-hmre'],
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.json/,
        loaders: ['json'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        loaders: [
          'style?sourceMap',
          'css?sourceMap&modules&importLoaders=3&localIdentName=[folder]--[local]--[hash:base64:2]',
          'resolve-url',
          'postcss',
          'sass?sourceMap',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(ico|jpg|png|gif|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url',
        query: {
          limit: 5000,
          name: 'static/[name]-[hash:6].[ext]',
        },
      },
      // icons loader
      {
        test: /icon\.svg$/,
        loaders: ['babel', 'svg-react', `svgo?${svgoConfig}`],
      },
      // svg loader excluding the .icon.svg files
      {
        test: /^(?!.*icon\.svg$).*\.svg$/,
        loaders: ['url?limit=5000'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loaders: ['html-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  postcss: () => [autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie > 9']})],
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      React: 'react', // provides React globally so that we don't need to import it
      cssModules: 'react-css-modules',
      classnames: 'classnames',
      Logger: 'universal/utils/log',
    }),
    // outputs a json file with the paths of the generated assets
    new AssetsPlugin({
      filename: 'webpack-assets.json',
      path: path.resolve(root, 'dist'),
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __IS_BROWSER__: true,
    }),
  ],
};
```